# Alias method from Trait in Parent Class

Tags: php, inheritance, traits

I'm wondering if this is possible in PHP:

```
trait SomeTrait
{
    public function someMethod() { /* ... */ }
}

class Parent
{
    use SomeTrait;
}

class Child extends Parent
{
    /* Do something to rename someMethod() to someOtherMethod() */
    use someMethod as someOtherMethod; // Example

    public function someMethod()
    {
        // Do something different than SomeTrait::someMethod()
    }
}
```

In my actual use-case, the **Parent** class is a parent to several children (and none of them actually use the `someMethod()` that comes from the trait applied to the parent class. The Parent class is also part of an external library, so I cannot directly modify the source code.

The **Child** class in my actual use-case also relies on protected properties from the **Parent** class, so I'm fairly certain that I need to keep the inheritance.

Is this actually possible, or do I just need to deal with it, and use a different method name on the **Child** class in question?

Comment: Have you tried it? It should work fine and just override the trait method.

Comment: I am pretty sure that you need to do the alias in the parent class rather than the child class.  Unless you want to just override the someMethod implementation in the child class.

Comment: For Trait, on the manual, it is described clearly that  the precedence order is that members from the current class override Trait methods, which in turn override inherited methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you've got in the question should work fine if you just want to override it. As per [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php):

> The precedence order is that members from the current class override Trait methods, which in turn override inherited methods.

If you need to provide an alias in the child class, then you can re-`use` the trait in the child class, making use of the `as` operator to define an alias in the current class:

```
class Child extends Foo
{
  // This will re-import the trait into your child class, aliasing
  // any specified methods.
  use SomeTrait {
    someMethod as someOtherMethod;
  }

  public function someMethod() {
    $this->someOtherMethod();
  }
}
```

You can also control the visibility of the new alias, e.g.

```
use SomeTrait {
  someMethod as private someOtherMethod;
}
```

All that said, I don't really see the benefit of this, when you could just call

```
parent::someMethod();
```

after over-riding it. But it might be useful if you've got a particularly complex inheritance tree.

Full example here: https://eval.in/868453

Comment: Thanks! And yes, I do have a complex inheritance tree. This is a situation of the same word means two different things, and I don't even use the parent's version of the method (so I'm essentially just completely changing it).

Answer (score 0):

I literally tested this yesterday with the following code :-)

```
<?php

trait CanWhatever
{
    public function doStuff()
    {
        return 'result!';
    }
}

class X
{
    use CanWhatever;

    public function doStuff()
    {
        return 'overridden!';
    }
}

$x = new X();
echo $x->doStuff();
echo "\n\$x has ";
echo (class_uses($x, 'CanWhatever')) ? 'the trait' : 'no trait';
```

The output was:

```
overridden! 
$x has the trait
```

So keeping the name the same just overrides as per normal.

Check it out here https://3v4l.org/Vin2H

Comment: You're overriding a method from a trait in the class itself. I have a parent/child relationship where the trait is applied to the parent, and I need to override it in the child.

Comment: Yeah fair enough, it's still possible, but `class_uses()` would return false. https://3v4l.org/Lde3B